# Userultra WordPress Plugin Custamisation

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am looking to be able to customize my userultra plugin on my wordpress site so that i can change the color of my sign in and sign up button text. As you can see from the picture below my form isn't very exciting and you cannot really see the text in the button. http://prntscr.com/67bkbu

Basically what i am after is for someone to explain to me how i can edit and customize the buttons on my login and sign-up forms whilst using the wordpress plugin Userultra.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell how to do it when you only provide an image, but I'll try.

1. If you use a third party theme and not a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), install a plugin like [Simple Custom CSS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/). If you have [Jetpack](http://jetpack.me/) installed, you can activate the Custom CSS module too. This will enable you to add CSS (= style code) to your site's `<head>`.
2. On your site, hover over an element that you wish to change, f.ex. the button, click on the right mouse button and select "inspect element" in the menu. This will open the [Page Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector).
3. The HTML for the button can look different, but it is likely in `<input>` field with 'type="submit". Possibly it has a class too, or an id. You can add style to the field type, the id or the class.

f.ex. the submit button here at Stackoverflow looks like this:

```
<input tabindex="0" type="submit" value="Add Comment">
```

This is the HTML. In the inspector you likely see it to the left. There is no class, or id, so the style is set by the field type.
To the right in the inspector you can see the styles. The following is the CSS by which styles get added to the input field with type submit (and to other buttons).

```
input[type=submit], input[type=button], .button, a.button:link, a.button:visited, .btn {
    border: 2px solid #f00;
    background: #222;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #009afd;
    border: 1px solid #1777b7;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3) inset,0 1px 1px rgba(100,100,100,0.3);
    padding: 8px 10px 7px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

4. If you would want to make change to this style, you can copy it to the plugins CSS field (text area) and delete everything you do not wish to change.

f.ex. to change the background colour of the type 'submit' to black, the following could be added:

```
input[type=submit] {
    background: #000;
}
```

I hope that helps you on your way. Else, please post a link to the page, and describe in more detail what you would like to change. That is easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install any visual composer plugin into your site in order to customize color and other visual appearance. Now talking about button fonts then internet is stuffed with so many plugins that enable you to do so. For instance you can see [ilikenull.com](http://www.ilikenull.com/?s=Button%20plugin). Also you can visit some other sites like noorsplugin, graphpaperpress, graphpaperpress etc. for additional options.